# jqGrid permutation array

Tags: jqgrid

In jqGrid I am trying to use the permutation array for saving the reorder state of the columns.
For eg. Basic column state is `perm = [0,1,2,3,4]` column 3 is hidden and column 0 is the checkbox. Now I have a custom context menu which I use to finally give me a perm array of `[0,1,3,2,4]`
I have read in the documentation that the permutation array needs to start with 1, is this right?
When I try using "remapColumns" functions of the jqgrid and pass the perm array, it works fine. But if I try hiding and showing columns a couple of times, the column order is getting messed with.
Please help me understand what these indices for the permutation array stand for? Are they column indexes for visible columns? Should hidden columns be part of array? What happens in case of frozen columns? In some examples I have seen `perm = [0:1, 1:3, 2:2, 3:1]`
What is the correct way? I am using `grid.jqGrid("remapColumns", perm, true);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use also the last parameter of the function

```
grid.jqGrid("remapColumns", [0,1,3,2,4], true, false);
```

permutation, updateCells, keepHeader

[wiki:methods](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods)